# ffmpeg's segment_atclocktime cuts at inaccurate times for audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg's [segment](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) format to save files of an AAC stream to disk in hourly segments.
The segmenting works well, but the files are segmented/cut at different times in the clock each hour using `segment_atclocktime`

I would like each to be exactly on the hour, e.g. 12:00:00, 13:00:00 etc. Or at least, beginning after the hour and not before, e.g. 12:00:00, 13:00:01, 14:00:00 etc.

This is the basic command I have been using:

```
ffmpeg -i <stream>.aac -f segment -acodec copy -segment_atclocktime 1 -segment_time 3600 -strftime 1 %Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S.aac
```

Most files are produced at the desired time: 05:00:00, 06:00:00, 07:00:00, but one or two each day start at 08:59:59 (where 09:00:00 would be desired), or even 16:00:24.

I understand the segment needs to begin on a audio sample so it can't be perfect to the hour, but wondering how I can make it more consistent. Ideally, each hour's recording would begin at 00:00 or later, and not begin before the hour.

I have tried using `-min_seg_duration 3600`, `-reset_timestamps 1`
I am not sure how exactly to use `-segment_clocktime_wrap_duration` for audio, or whether `-segment_time_delta` applies to audio.

I'd appreciate any advice or understanding of how `segment_atclocktime` works with audio, as much on the internet seems video-focused.